# creating a method that calculates averages from an array (java)

Tags: java, arrays

Write a static method named calculateAverageWeight, to be added to the Bowl class, which is passed an array of Bowl objects, and returns the average weight of the Bowls in the array.

this is the Bowl class:

```
public class Bowl {
private double weight;
private boolean empty;
private String origin; // country of manufacture

public Bowl(double w, boolean e, String origin) {
    weight = w;
    empty = e;
    this.origin = origin;
}

public double getWeight() {
    return weight;
}

public boolean getEmpty() {
    return empty;
}

public String getOrigin() {
    return origin;
}

public void setEmpty(boolean emptyStatus) {
    empty = emptyStatus;
}

public String toString() {
    return ("from " + origin + " weight: " + weight);
}
```

The following code worked:

```
public static double calculateAverageWeight(Bowl[] bowls)
{
double sum=0;
double average=0;
for(int j=0; j<bowls.length; j++)
{
sum+=bowls[j].getWeight();
average=sum/bowls.length;
}
return average;
}
```

but I don't understand why my most recent code didn't as they seem to run almost identically to me?:

```
public static double calculateAverageWeight(Bowl[] bowls){
double sum=0;
double k=bowls.length;
for(int j=0; j<bowls.length; j++){
sum=sum+bowls[j].getWeight();}
double average=sum/k;
return average;}
```

Comment: What happens when you run it?

Comment: What's the problem? We aren't mind readers; you have to actually tell us.

Comment: You are probably going to want to cast one of your ints in that division to a (double), otherwise I think you get a whole number assigned to average. I'm debugging this from memory though so I could be wrong

Comment: it says that I have compilation errors, my mistake I thought i had written that in the original post.

Comment: @user2163240 Please edit your question with the exact error messages and line numbers you are getting.

Comment: Also might want to tag the language if you want syntactical help not just array logic (which seems to be all good)

Comment: There is also a loss of precision error getWeight() returns a double but your sum is an int

Comment: okay so I changed my sum variable from an int to a double but still getting the same error

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to manipulate arrays. Find the average. Beginner Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12002332/how-to-manipulate-arrays-find-the-average-beginner-java)

Answer (score 0):

```
public static double calculateAverageWeight(Bowl[] bowls)
{
    double sum=0;
    double average=0;
    for(int j=0; j<bowls.length; j++)
    {
        sum+=bowls[j].getWeight();
        average=sum/bowls.length;
    }
    return average;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The code for the **calculateAverageWeight** is OK, but you're missing a "}" at the end of the Bowl class.

Also, your  **calculateAverageWeight** method must be inside another class, so you may be missing something there too. May you post your code ?