# Averaging Items in an Array, in an Array

Tags: java, arrays, average

I want to loop through my array list roster and for each Student item I want to return the average of an array of grades. I know there are 3 grades so this code works, but how can I implement this if I don't know how many grades are in the Student's grades array before hand?

```
    public static void printAverageGrades(){
    System.out.println("Print Average Grades");
    for(Student item : roster)
    {
        double div = roster.size();
        **double average = (item.getGrades()[0] + item.getGrades()[1] + item.getGrades()[2]) / div;**
        System.out.printf("%.2f \n", average);
    }
}
```

Comment: So you're saying that `getGrades` returns an `int[]`?

Comment: The answer will involve a `for` loop, and possibly `.length` which gives you the length of an array.  I'd suggest you find an online tutorial and learn about those.

Comment: It returns the double properly, but I have to manually enter each position e.g. item.getGrades()[0] + item.getGrades()[1]...I want toloop through the grades array based on the length of the array to return each individual double so that I can average them?

Comment: `for (int grade : item.getGrades() {...}` would allow you to sum the grades without knowing the number of grades

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to manipulate arrays. Find the average. Beginner Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12002332/how-to-manipulate-arrays-find-the-average-beginner-java)

Answer (score 0):

You can do this two ways.  The more preferable Java 8 way is listed first.

- Use `Arrays.stream` to encapsulate the array as a stream, then getting the average is just a couple of method calls away.

  ```
  double avg = Arrays.stream(item.getGrades()).average().getAsDouble();
  ```
- Use another `for` loop and keep a running total of the elements.  Don't forget to manually coerce your numerator to a `double` or you'll run into integer division.

  ```
  int sum = 0;
  for(int i : item.getGrades()) {
      sum += i;
  }
  double avg = (sum * 1.0) / item.getGrades().length;
  ```

In practice, **never hard-code your index locations.**  You can ***always*** get the length of an array [using `.length`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23730092/1079354).

Comment: Thank you! I knew I didn't want to hard code them, this solution worked perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

You can just use this function, in which would iterate through the array, by dynamically iterating through for loop, we compute sum.
Then average would be divided by the length of array.

```
double getAverage(double[] data)
{
    double sum = 0.0;
    for(double a : data)
        sum += a;
    return sum/data.length;
}
```

Comment: If you're going to write a code-only solution, it's preferable to explain what the code's doing so that the OP has some inkling of what the solution means.

Comment: @Makoto it was quite self explanatory.

Comment: I don't disagree but that doesn't mean that it's just OK to leave only code around.  It's the difference between giving them a fish and teaching them to fish.

Comment: True. Updated my answer.